# Prove that the set of all functions is not a group under function composition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, function-and-relation-composition

> Consider the set $F$ of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$.  There are $3^3= 27$ of them.
>   Prove this set is not a group under function composition.

I thought that it violates the inverse element property, but not sure how.  I believe identity in our case is the identity map.  Not really sure how to show an example how it fails under inverse.  Help much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea. Consider this: Is there an inverse of the constant function $f$ defined by $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1$?

Comment: are you referring to 1 in another set?  this function does not exist

Comment: @zzz, I think Hayden referred to the function $\;f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1\;$. This thing doesn't have an inverse under composition.

Comment: @zzzz Yes, what Timbuc said is correct.  It is the function defined by $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1$.